# React JS need to set multiple state values from dropdown item list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown list from an array of values like mapped to a dropdown and a handleSelect

```
const handleSelect = (e) => {
     handleShow()
    setCommunityName(e)
}
```

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Join Community" onSelect={handleSelect} hidden={showJoin}>
    {communities.map(data =>
    <Dropdown.Item title={data.CommunityName} key={data.id}
    eventKey={data.CommunityName}>{data.CommunityName}</Dropdown.Item>)}
</DropdownButton>
```

Right now only data.CommunityName is set in state, but I would also like to set the state of data.id as well. I was trying to do something like this?

```
const handleSelect = (e, i) => {
    handleShow()
    setCommunityName(e)
    setCommunityId(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the entire object as value?

```
<Dropdown.Item title={data.CommunityName} key={data.id}
eventKey={data}>{data.CommunityName}</Dropdown.Item>)}
```

```
const handleSelect = (e) => {
    handleShow()
    setCommunityName(e.CommunityName)
    setCommunityId(e.id)
}
```

Comment: I tried printing the values and I get undefined when calling handleSelect

Comment: I just ended up passing the id since that it what was needed for the API call. That method just passed an object and I was unable to access the values. I was probably missing